# Using jQuery how do I fade in one statement over another indefinitely?

Tags: jquery, css, fadein, fade, fadeout

I want to fade 3 or more statements out and in, indefinitely.  Here is the code:

```
    <div class= "background">
    <h6>
    <div id="one">This is the first statement</div>
    <div id="two">This is the second statement</div>
    <div id="third">You get the point</div>
    </h6> 
    </div>
```

I worded the question wrong:  I want `#two` to replace `#one` and `#three` to replace `#two` and `#one` to replace `#three` so on.  And yeah i did look all over the place.  Geez sorry for needing help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(){
$('.background').fadeToggle('slow');
},1000);
```

**UPDATE**

Something like this?

```
var k = ["#one","#two","#third"]
var cnt = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    $(k[cnt]).fadeToggle('slow').siblings().hide();
    cnt++;
if(cnt ==3){cnt = 0;}    
},2000);
```

Demo here : http://jsbin.com/urikah/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` one after the other (jQuery's animation queue will make the second one wait until the first is done) with a completion function on the last one that starts the whole process over again like this:

```
function fadeForever(sel) {
    $(sel).fadeOut().fadeIn(function() {
        fadeForever(sel);
    });
}

fadeForever("#one, #two, #three");
```

Or, if you want the whole background div to fade, you can just use:

```
fadeForever(".background");
```

You can, of course, add a timing argument to the `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` if you want to control the fade time.

Comment: I want one div to replace another.  Not all three to fade in and out together.  I understand how I was confusing.  Thanks a lot for trying.  I appreciate it.

Comment: @Niko - unclear original question then.  Must sleep, can't work on your question now.

Answer (score 0):

**Demo**: http://jsbin.com/ubiqob/5/edit/

**EDIT:** I updated my jsbin to better match your example...

I had a `fade` class to your divs, just for convenience:

```
<div class= "background">
   <h6>
      <div class="fade">This is the first statement</div>
      <div class="fade">This is the second statement</div>
      <div class="fade">You get the point</div>
   </h6> 
</div>
```

With the following CSS class:

```
.fade {
   position: absolute;
   display: none;
}
```

And finally the javascript code:

```
var j = 0,
    n = ('.fade').length;
    $('.fade:first').fadeIn(1000);

function change() {  
    $('.fade:visible').fadeOut(1000, function() {
    j = j + 1;
    $($('.fade')[j%n]).fadeIn(1000);
  });
}

setInterval(change, 2000);
```